# PHP PDO. Should I throw an exception if update query rowcount is zero?

Tags: php, mysql, exception, pdo, sql-update

I am working on my first OO PHP website.

When I am calling an update function, for example to unblock an user, I will check if this was successful. If not I will throw an exception like this:

Business layer code:

```
if($DB->unblockUserByUsername($username) === FALSE){ 
    throw new DBExpectedRowUpdate("Expected row update."); 
}
```

Called function in DB Class:

```
public function unblockUserByUsername($input){ 
    $sql = "UPDATE user SET ......"; //<- imagine valid update query 
    return $this->updateQuery($sql) === 1; // Return bool
}
```

I thought, I don't have update functions where I don't expect a row to be updated. So I will end up doing this check every time I call an update function in my upper layer.

So I thought isn't it better to throw this exception in the DB class update function itself? Like:

```
private function updateQuery($sql, $dontThrowError = FALSE){ 
    $this->CheckConn(); try {
         $affectedRows = $this->DBH->exec($sql.";"); 
         $this->DBH->commit();

         //Check affected rows count
         if($affectedRows === 0 && $dontThrowError !== TRUE){
             throw new DBExpectedRowUpdate("Expected row update.");
         }

         return $affectedRows;
    } catch(PDOException $e) { 
         $this->DBH->rollback(); 
         return -1;  // Also throw error here
    }
}
```

I am asking this because I can't seem to find a lot about this subject or best practice examples for a similar case.

Comment: *When using UPDATE, MySQL will not update columns where the new value is the same as the old value.* so, if no value changes 0 affectedRows will appear and it is not exceptional case.

Comment: So you are saying throwing an error in this case is not database logic expected behavior. That makes sense to me.